# Javascript, array is passing "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function replacesrc() {
    var array= new Array();
    array[1,2,3,4]=document.getElementById("From").value.split(" ");
    document.getElementById("map").src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr="+array[1]+"+"+array[2]+"+"+array[3]+",+North+Augusta,+SC&amp;daddr=Hilton+Head+Island,+SC&amp;geocode=FYn4_wEd4BQd-ym_ve9aOTP4iDGvGGPbsAEwOw%3BFfyU6wEdINAv-ymtGdOO3Hn8iDE9KKLreqblLA&amp;aq=1&amp;oq=hi&amp;sll=33.623768,-80.925293&amp;sspn=5.551464,10.129395&amp;hl=en&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=32.88718,-81.37587&amp;spn=1.3416,1.24656&amp;output=embed"
    document.getElementById("test").value=array[1,2,3,4];
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="map" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=2000+Knobcone+Ave,+North+Augusta,+SC&amp;daddr=Hilton+Head+Island,+SC&amp;geocode=FYn4_wEd4BQd-ym_ve9aOTP4iDGvGGPbsAEwOw%3BFfyU6wEdINAv-ymtGdOO3Hn8iDE9KKLreqblLA&amp;aq=1&amp;oq=hi&amp;sll=33.623768,-80.925293&amp;sspn=5.551464,10.129395&amp;hl=en&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=32.88718,-81.37587&amp;spn=1.3416,1.24656&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
<br />From: <input id="From" type="text" /> <button onClick="replacesrc()">Directions</button><input id="test" type="text" value="test" />

<br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=embed&amp;saddr=2000+Knobcone+Ave,+North+Augusta,+SC&amp;daddr=Hilton+Head+Island,+SC&amp;geocode=FYn4_wEd4BQd-ym_ve9aOTP4iDGvGGPbsAEwOw%3BFfyU6wEdINAv-ymtGdOO3Hn8iDE9KKLreqblLA&amp;aq=1&amp;oq=hi&amp;sll=33.623768,-80.925293&amp;sspn=5.551464,10.129395&amp;hl=en&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=32.88718,-81.37587&amp;spn=1.3416,1.24656" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>

</body>
</html>
```

That is my code. It keeps passing it as undefined. Could someone help me out here? I've tried difference ways to fix this. But I still can not. From my point I did it right, cause I put a test function to see what it is sending and I get the same exact thing back, but when it put it in the src it put it as undefined.

Comment: Looks like someone is used to php's [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in place of the first two lines. Then access the elements starting at 0, so `array[0]` is the first item, `array[1]` is the second, etc.

```
var array = document.getElementById("From").value.split(" ");
```

And for the last line use this:

```
document.getElementById("test").value = array.join();
```

#### Why?

`array[1,2,3,4]` doesn't do what you expect. It's rather unintuitive. The commas here do not let you access multiple array indices.

`1,2,3,4` is an expression using the oddball comma `,` operator three times. For an expression `a,b` expression `a` is evaluated and then thrown away. Next `b` is evaluated and that becomes the value of the comma operator.

```
1,2,3,4 == ((1,2),3),4
        == (2,3),4
        == 3,4
        == 4
```

So writing `array[1,2,3,4]` is in fact identical with `array[4]`.

Comment: Okay! Thank you! It worked and now I understand it.
But I do have another issue if you can help me with. It is not updating my map now, but it is passing the correct vars.

Comment: @Matt I recommend posting that as a separate question.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for the help. Would rep you or vote up what ever it is called, but I don't have 15 rep.